# WPF Animate DataGridCell text BlurEffect with DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, datagrid, storyboard

I have a datagrid that I am trying to blur and fade in text when row data is changed and certain criteria is met.   I have everything working except the addition of blurring the text in the animation and bringing it into focus with an animation (as the text opacity also fades in).

The error I'm currently getting is "Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Effect.BlurEffect'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.".   If I remove the animation part, the blur works as expected - I guess I just need to know how to properly reference the effect so I can animate it.

The way it works is this:   I have a staticResource set in my columns sets an animation when a datatrigger criteria is met with a value in an invisible column (named: changed).

I've done about 4 hours of searching now without finding any documentation or really even any examples of doing this with a datatrigger.    Any assistance would be most appreciated.   Below is an example of my XAML

```html
<DataGrid x:Name="dgDisplay" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource headersVisible}" AlternatingRowBackground="Lightblue" AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="None" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="cellHighlight">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger
                                Binding="{Binding changed}" Value="S">
                                <Setter Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <BlurEffect Radius="10" KernelType="Gaussian" x:Name="blur"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="FadeS" >
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                                From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                                AutoReverse="False"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Effect.BlurEffect" 
                                                From="10" To="0" Duration="00:00:1" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource cellHighlight}" Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" FontWeight="Bold" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellHighlight}" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I thought about it a little and changed the target property to BlurEffect.Radius - now I don't throw an error, but the blur doesn't get animated.   I've tried (TextBlock).(BlurEffect.Radius) and a few other variations only to get an error.   Getting closer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgDisplay" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource headersVisible}" AlternatingRowBackground="Lightblue" AlternationCount="2" GridLinesVisibility="None" >
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="cellHighlight">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Border>
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <BlurEffect Radius="0" KernelType="Gaussian" x:Name="blurEffect"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger
                            Binding="{Binding changed}" Value="S">
                                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard x:Name="FadeS" >
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Opacity)"
                                            From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1" 
                                            AutoReverse="False"  />
                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="blurEffect" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Radius"
                                            From="10" To="0" Duration="00:00:1" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource cellHighlight}" Header="Col1" Binding="{Binding Col1}" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" CellStyle="{StaticResource cellHighlight}" Binding="{Binding Col2}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thanks - that worked perfectly.  The controlTemplate apparently allows you to use the TargetName, which was part of my problem.   Thanks again!